# How to create objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I want to create objects with properties:

```
{
type,
geometry: {
  type,
  coordinates;
}
}
```

I tried to create it by the constructor:

```
function element(x, u) {
    this.type = 'type';
    this.geometry.type = 'type';
    this.geometry.coordinates = [x, y];
}
```

In fact, i cannot do  this that way.

How do I need to create these object in the proper way?

Comment: What do you mean, "I cannot do this that way"?  What goes wrong? Are there errors?  (One thing: you used `u` as a parameter name but refer to `y` in the function body.)

Comment: Yes, i know about this mistake. I got error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a typo (`u` -> `y`); additionally,  you can't assign `this.geometry.type` if `this.geometry` is undefined.

```
function element(x, y) {
    this.type = 'type';
    this.geometry = {};
    this.geometry.type = 'type';
    this.geometry.coordinates = [x, y];
}
```

Also consider looking into `class`es.

Answer (score 0):

For the object structure you've provided, you could it as simple as that:

```
var yourNewObject = {
    type: 'typeValue',
    geometry: {
      type: 'geometryTypeValue',
      coordinates 'coordinatesValue';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but if I want to create several objects of this structure? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an object in constructor style then you can do something like this.

```js
function element(x, y, type) {
  this.type = 'type';
  this.geometry = new Geometry();

  function Geometry() {
    this.coordinates = [x, y];
    this.type = type;
  }
}
var el = new element(1, 2, 'mytype');
console.log(el);
```

Comment: But now I got the object like: GeoMapElement {type: "Featuree", geometry: Geometry}

Comment: add extra argument for hardcoded `type` and rename function `element` to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Object APIs provided by JS recursively in order to create and   add objects to any other object, for instance -

```
Object.defineProperties()    
Object.defineProperty()
Object.assign()
Object.create()
.....
.....
```